# Inferring vitamin D level from levels of parathyroid hormone, vitamin B6 and calcium

Tags: micronutrients, blood-tests

Given a blood test that contains the levels of parathyroid hormone, vitamin B6 and calcium, how to infer the level of vitamin D?

Comment: Hmm, why do you think the level of vitamin D can be inferred from anything?

Comment: I'm still interested in this question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Exposure to adequate sunlight is a better predictor of vitamin D levels than PTH, B6, and calcium.  It's unlikely that a solid enough correlation exists between those and D.  If you're rarely exposed to sunlight wearing bathing suit attire during peak UVB hours (11am - 1pm in most of North America), and you also don't take a supplemental form, you're very likely to be on the low side, if not outright deficient.

The only way to know for sure is to have your 25-hydroxy vitamin D levels checked via bloodworm.  If you like, you can [go here](http://www.grassrootshealth.net/daction) to participate in a study that will let you measure your levels a couple times a year for 60 dollars.

Vitamin D is arguably the most important vitamin to supplement with for most people in developed countries.  Now being called a 'master hormone' by some researchers, it controls over 10% of the human genome through epigenetic influences.  Correction of vitamin D levels has been associated with improvements in a wide variety of illnesses, from depression to autoimmune disorders to hormonal imbalances.

Optimal dosage is anywhere from 5,000 ius per day to as high as 20,000 ius for some people, though this is excessive for most.

Comment: Lots of assertions of facts and not one citation to support them.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. This site requires [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/). Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site. Thanks.